# Learning RoR and Mongo, why not count the array for votes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, data-modeling

I'm completely new to Mongo and RoR, coming from a PHP background.

I was just going through this tutorial about data modelling
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MongoDB+Data+Modeling+and+Rails

and was struck with the question of why the tutorial would recommend storing the votes in a field and updating that field as

```
db.stories.update({_id: story_id, voters: {'$ne': user_id}}, 
  {'$inc': {votes: 1}, '$push': {voters: user_id}});
```

instead of just

```
db.stories.update({_id: story_id, voters: {'$ne': user_id}}, 
  {'$push': {voters: user_id}});
```

and then counting then

```
Story.voters.count
```

to get the count of the number of users who have voted?

I know it's a tutorial, but it doesn't seem like the most efficient way to manage the data.

Comment: Yup. You're right. Used to be that `length` (the attr you're looking for) wasn't cached, but now it is so you should just use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial could do a better job by explaining the purpose of maintaining the count cache field (votes), since it's only needed if you intend to do range queries on the array's size.

From [the docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-ConditionalOperator%3A%24size):

> You cannot use $size to find a range
>   of sizes (for example: arrays with
>   more than 1 element). If you need to
>   query for a range, create an extra
>   size field that you increment when you
>   add elements.

In the future we probably won't have to do that as the query capabilities continue to grow.  See JIRA ticket [SERVER-478](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-478).